# Facebook PHP SDK Age Range

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I'm creating a facebook application that allows users to register at my site using data from facebook, then I need to retrieve these data.
The code I wrote is as follows:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
        $session,
        'GET',
        '/me'
    );
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
$user = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
```

And then I get some information with:

```
echo "Name: " . $graphObject->getProperty('name');
echo "<br/>";
echo "Email: " . $graphObject->getProperty('email');
```

etc.
The problem is that I don't know how to get the age range, because if I try

```
echo "Age range: " . $graphObject->getProperty('age_range');
```

or

```
echo "Age range: " . $graphObject->getProperty('agerange');
```

It returns an empty space, without providing any data.
So, how can I retrieve age range infos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`age_range` is not a default field so you will have to ask for it using `/me?fields=age_range`